# Back button to ajax results, advice request

Tags: ajax, back

I am trying solve the back button issue within my app. The scenario is:

I have a home page with a search form which sends and receives data with $.ajax(), then the results loaded through ajax, their links points to a controller that won't be done by GET in ajax so that means that the page will be refreshed (so the home page with the results looks like this: http://url/en/home and a result link may look like this http://url/fetch/data/x123av).

The problem is which is the best way fix that when click back button to return the results from the search box?

I have found some answers in stackoverflow related to my question:
http://code.google.com/p/reallysimplehistory
http://tkyk.github.com/jquery-history-plugin

But from the documentation of those plugins, they all work by checking the hash change which I don't have.

Hope I have explained well enough, and I do have searched stackoverflow and google for a solution but I didn't find one that is close to this or either I've jumped over it...

Please just point me to the right way :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But from the documentation of those plugins, they all work by checking
>   the hash change which I don't have.

If you want to handle the back button with AJAX request you will have to redesign your application so that it works with hashes as that's the only way. Changing the fragment portion of an url doesn't trigger a page reload but it is added to the history, so when you press the back button you are able to detect this change without navigating away from the page.

As mentioned by SLaks in the comments section another possibility is to use the [HTML5 history API](http://html5demos.com/history) but obviously this assumes that the client browser supports it.

Comment: Or use the HTML5 history API.

Comment: @SLaks, very good point. I will update my answer to include this valuable information.

Comment: ok so there is no way of showing what was being seen when you click the browser Back button if you don't use hash but the HTML5 History API!

Having in mind that I have the links as explained in the question above, how should I do so?

Comment: @w0rldart, the HTML5 history API is implemented differently between the browsers. Fortunately there's the [history.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js) plugin which simplifies its usage.

Comment: deactivated ajax, but tnx for the help